# Alexa: Can we combine flash briefing and conversational custom skill together?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

I have read many articles which specifies flash briefing as a separate skill and custom skill as an independent skill

- Is it possible to combine flash briefing and custom skill together or is it not available right now?

Comment: I'm also having this same question...

Comment: @JoseA check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Alexa don't have a way to do it in a single skill per:
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/159904/alexa-can-we-combine-flash-briefing-and-conversati.html

Comment: Shoot! Thank you so much!!